# Examples where top engines in a tournament match don't agree in evaluation

Tags: engines, tournament, evaluation

I'd like to know about computer games of some recent  tournaments where two top engines diverge in evaluation of a position, in the sense that both  think are winning the game (or both losing). I saw a match in the last CCC where Stockfish as white had +3 in his evaluation and Leela -3, that was the maximum I've ever seen.

This is interesting because usually the two engines seem to agree all the time about which one is winning (or at least one thinks it is winning/losing and the other thinks it is a draw) even if there's a gap between the two evaluations.

Best by now I found :

https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-elite-round&game=508 : about +1 and -1

---

**EDIT:**

It seems I had an hallucination about the game between Stockfish and Leela

Comment: Do you have a link to that match?

Comment: I'm certain AlphaZero doesn't participate in TCEC. I'm also skeptical there was a +3 vs. -3 divergence in the last TCEC season either involving Stockfish, and would like to see the game, as well.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to find it !

Comment: I did end up finding one where they do differ quite a lot, but i dont know one of the engines so i cant say it is a top engine. This match [https://www.chess.com/computer-chess-championship#event=romantic-openings-evans-gambit-accepted&game=327](https://www.chess.com/computer-chess-championship#event=romantic-openings-evans-gambit-accepted&game=327). In move 40 the eval is +2.17 vs -4.33

Comment: @Isac Pedone is currently mid-table in TCEC league 1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCEC_Season_21#League_1) while Komodo is the third strongest engine around.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not a question.

Comment: @Toby Harnish ? It is a specific question instead, indeed two answers were provided

Comment: First, it asks for "Examples where top engines in a tournament match don't agree in evaluation ", while the question itself had already answered it. "I saw a match in the last CCC where Stockfish as white had +3 in his evaluation and Leela -3, that was the maximum I've ever seen.", it seems to me that the question had already answered it.

Comment: 1) There is a edit section 2) ExampleS

Comment: @Tortar, the op asks that if there is a game where two engines had a different evaluation about it. And clearly you can see that the op himself answered it. Maybe I missunderstood something?

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding that I'm asking for *examples*, not just one, where this happened *recently*, also even if I thought to have seen +3 and -3 as it is explained in the edit section I didn't find it so I was really probably wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found through a script several games where (not so big) divergence occurs!

I analized roughly 3000 games with time control 15+3 and just 10 show a notable divergence.

**It's interesting and intuitively correct that this happens a lot more when black wins!** Indeed in the list below there are 3 wins by white, 6 by black and 1 draw even if black wins much more rarely than white between engines.

---

**CCC main league 2021** :

[Stockfish classic - Stooflees](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-main-league&game=9) : +1.41 vs. -2.53

[Komodo - Rubi](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-main-league&game=192) : Long divergence with pick +1.22 vs. -1.35

**CCC elite round 2021** :

[Stooflees - Ethereal](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-elite-round&game=357) : +0.84 vs. -1.75

[Stockfish - Stooflees](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-elite-round&game=391) : +2.91 vs -0.27

[SlowChess - Stoofvless](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-elite-round&game=407) : +2,76 vs. -1.04

[Ethereal- Stoofvless](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-elite-round&game=508)  : Long divergence with pick +1,07 vs. -0.97

**CCC final 2021 Stockfish - Lc0**:

[Game 9](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-finals&game=9) : Long divergence with pick +0.46 vs. -2.19

[Game 409](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=ccc-rapid-2021-finals&game=409) : +0.37 vs -1.99

**CCC 2021 Leela vs Dragon round 2** :

[Game 2](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=leela-vs-dragon-round-2&game=2)  : Long divergence with pick +0.34 vs. -1.04

[Game 68](https://www.chess.com/it/computer-chess-championship#event=leela-vs-dragon-round-2&game=68) : Long divergence with pick +0.89 vs -1.13. This game is strange, the two engines don't agree with drawing the game, 307 moves are played!

Comment: Sounds like great work! We can agree that these positions are very important indeed. How did you download the games together with evaluations from *both* engines?

Comment: Initially I thought I would have to write some HTML request but in the end I found that in the download button of one game of a certain event on chess.com you can go on the event section and download all the games of that event  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This happens, but it's rare and is getting rarer. [Here's](https://tcec-chess.com/#div=p&game=130&season=21) a very recent game between Stoofvlees and Komodo Dragon displaying such eval divergence. The discrepancy was only there for a few moves, too.

**Edit**: As I said this does not happen often and it's getting rarer. Examples of Stockfish-Leela games in the past where it happened are [this game from Season 15](https://tcec-chess.com/#div=sf&game=61&season=15) and [this one from Season 18](https://tcec-chess.com/#div=sf&game=13&season=18); both games are over a year old at this point and involve versions >100 elo weaker than today's.

Comment: this case is not so interesting because the two evalutions are always of the same sign

Comment: @Tortar not exactly - on move 138 Stoofvlees was +ve and Komodo Dragon was -ve.

Comment: yes, but very tiny difference

Comment: @Tortar we're lucky there's even divergence in the first place. If you can find a position with a substantial eval divergence between today's Stockfish/Leela, I'm sure Jeroen (the person who makes the TCEC opening books for the suprefinal) will be interested.

Comment: I found some interesting games between the two, but not so big gaps